# Pixijs with Meteor getting black canvas

Tags: meteor, pixi.js

I am trying to figure out on how to use Pixi.js with Meteor but all I am getting in a black screen.
Here is an example at Meteorpad:

http://meteorpad.com/pad/F23Du5XsCKMw9ZrWa

Can anyone please help with what might be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I have checked your meteorpad and I can see in the console that you're having a problem with CORS policy. Think this may be a reason the image is not loaded.

Comment: Thanks mate, Yeah I saw that, I fixed it locally with a local image but still have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out, my code before:

```
 var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0x66FF99),
        renderer = new PIXI.autoDetectRenderer( 900,500, document.getElementById("stage")),
        texture0 = PIXI.Texture.fromImage('http://www.greensock.com/_img/codepen/bezierCreature/creature.png');

  kzRocket = new PIXI.Sprite(texture0);

  kzRocket.position.x = 30;
  kzRocket.position.y = 140;
  stage.addChild(kzRocket);
```

It was missing the render call at the end. Here is the fixed version for anyone else who gets stuck like me.

```
 var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0x66FF99),
        renderer = new PIXI.autoDetectRenderer( 900,500, document.getElementById("stage")),
        texture0 = PIXI.Texture.fromImage('http://www.greensock.com/_img/codepen/bezierCreature/creature.png');

  kzRocket = new PIXI.Sprite(texture0);

  kzRocket.position.x = 30;
  kzRocket.position.y = 140;
  stage.addChild(kzRocket);
  renderer.render(stage);
```